# angularjs: access inner scope from outer scope

Tags: scope, angularjs

I am trying to move bits from a parent controller inside child controllers in an angularjs app to not pollute the main controller too much.
Here's a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/5RMPV/
So when I click the change button, the third letter should change to 'X'.
Initially the item_change() function was inside the main controller and was doing `$scope.items[idx] = 'X'` and this worked just fine. However, since I moved it inside the ItemCtrl, I have no idea how to access it for the 3rd element.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For simple data modeling, a model's data is associated with a single controller (via $scope), and behavior/methods for that model are functions on that single controller.  When you need something more complex, as in your example -- multiple controllers need to access the same data/model -- you can $scope.$emit events and $scope.$on listen for events, or (the better way) do what Gloopy shows: put the model's data (and behaviors/functions) into a service, then give the controllers access via injection.

Comment: I was initially thinking of making the items real js objects each having the item_change() method so I could call $scope.items[3].item_change() but it might be overkill. I'll go with Gloopy's suggestion for now. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to move things out of your main controller is to share and make all changes to the data between controllers inside a service or factory (described pretty nicely in [this article](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-1-architecture/)).

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloopy/nFgL9/). You would just need to inject the `itemsService` into any controller you would want to access the items data in.

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .service('itemsService', function(){
        var items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

        return{
            getItems: function(){
                return items;
            },
            changeItem: function(index, value){
                items[index] = value;
            }
        }
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, itemsService) {
        $scope.items = itemsService.getItems();       

        $scope.change = function(idx) {
            itemsService.changeItem(idx, 'X');
        }

    })
```

Comment: oh...makes sense. Still wrapping my head around the "angular way". Thanks